# I am required to create a python program that requires 3 attempts and 5 rounds, but instead allows infinite attempts

Tags: python

To start i am very new to programming as i am doing it as a course so please be patient with me please.This program instead allows infinite guesses until the correct answer and all rounds are printed at once instead round by round I just need guidance on what im doing wrong because I am failing to see what I did incorrect

```
import random

sides = 6           #number of sides for a die
userguess = -1      #user's guess,  1 - 6 inclusive
rolled = -1         #number rolled, 1 - 6 inclusive
computerpoints = 0  #computer's score, 0 - 5 max
humanpoints = 0     #human user's score, 0 - 5 max
rightguess = False  #flag for correct guess
numguesses = 0      #counts the number of guesses per round

#RULES
print("Welcome to the Guess Game!\n\n RULES:")
print("1. We will play five rounds.")
print("2. Each round you will guess the number rolled on a six-sided die.")
print("3. If you guess the correct value in three or fewer tries\n"
        "   then you score a point, otherwise I score a point.")
print("4. Whoever has the most points after five rounds wins.")


#play five rounds
for r in range(1, 5): 
    #roll the die to start the round
    print("\n\nROUND " ,  r)
    print("-------")
    random.seed(11)  
    rolled = random.randrange(sides)+1
    print("The computer has rolled the die.")
    print("You have three guesses.");

    #loop gives user up to three guesses
    numguesses = 0;
    while numguesses < 3 and not rightguess:
        #loop for input & validation: must be in range 1 to 6 inclusive
        userguess = int(input("What is your guess [1-6]?"))
        while userguess < 1 and userguess > 6:
            userguess = int(input("   Please enter a valid guess [1-6]!"))


        if rolled == userguess:
            rightguess = True
            print("   Correct!")

        else:
            print("   Incorrect guess.")

    #if the user guessed right, they get a point
    #otherwise the computer gets a point
    if rightguess:
        humanpoints = humanpoints + 1;
    else:
        computerpoints = computerpoints + 1;

    #display the answer and scores
    print("\n*** The correct answer was: " , rolled , " ***\n")
    print("Scores:")
    print("  You: \t\t" , humanpoints)
    print("  Computer: \t" , computerpoints)
    print("")


    if computerpoints > humanpoints : 
        print("*** You Lose! ***")
    else:
        print("*** You Win! ***")

    print("Thanks for playing the Guess Game!")
```

Comment: So switch the 3 and 5?

Answer (score 0):

1. `range(1, 5)` returns the numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4, but not 5. So in order to have 5 rounds, you need to use `range(1, 6)`
2. You never increment `numguesses`, which means that the guessing loop will only end when the user has made the right guess.
3. I don't think you reset `rightguess` for successive rounds.

Comment: sorry i'm really new to this and I'm trying to still wrap my head around this, would mind showing me because I am a visual learner and since this was in a previous assignment i figured i made this same mistake

Answer (score 0):

This is my corrected program, please reply if you see anything else that needs fixing please and thank you

```
import random

sides = 6           #number of sides for a die
userguess = -1      #user's guess,  1 - 6 inclusive
rolled = -1         #number rolled, 1 - 6 inclusive
computerpoints = 0  #computer's score, 0 - 5 max
humanpoints = 0     #human user's score, 0 - 5 max
rightguess = False  #flag for correct guess
numguesses = 0      #counts the number of guesses per round

#RULES
print("Welcome to the Guess Game!\n\n RULES:")
print("1. We will play five rounds.")
print("2. Each round you will guess the number rolled on a six-sided die.")
print("3. If you guess the correct value in three or fewer tries\n"
        "   then you score a point, otherwise I score a point.")
print("4. Whoever has the most points after five rounds wins.")


#play five rounds
for r in range(1, 6): 
    #roll the die to start the round
    print("\n\nROUND " ,  r)
    print("-------")
    random.seed(11)  
    rolled = random.randrange(sides)+1
    print("The computer has rolled the die.")
    print("You have three guesses.");

    #loop gives user up to three guesses
    numguesses = 0;
    while numguesses < 3 and not rightguess:
        #loop for input & validation: must be in range 1 to 6 inclusive
        numguesses = numguesses + 1
        userguess = int(input("What is your guess [1-6]?"))
        while userguess < 1 and userguess > 6:
            userguess = int(input("   Please enter a valid guess [1-6]!"))


        if rolled == userguess:
            rightguess = True
            print("   Correct!")

        else:
            print("   Incorrect guess.")

    #if the user guessed right, they get a point
    #otherwise the computer gets a point
    if rightguess:
        humanpoints = humanpoints + 1;
    else:
        computerpoints = computerpoints + 1;

    #display the answer and scores
    print("\n*** The correct answer was: " , rolled , " ***\n")
    print("Scores:")
    print("  You: \t\t" , humanpoints)
    print("  Computer: \t" , computerpoints)
    print("")


    if computerpoints > humanpoints : 
        print("*** You Lose! ***")
    else:
        print("*** You Win! ***")

    print("Thanks for playing the Guess Game!")
```